# Export Apple Notes

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, notes.app

I want to export (or transfer) all notes from the Apple Notes app to a note taking app on a different platform. So I need to bulk copy or move all the notes I have in Apple Notes to Linux. Is there any way to do this?

From what I've tried, the Notes app on the MacBook can only export a single note as an unmodifiable PDF, by using the export as PDF button. I want to be able to export all notes in the Notes app in one go as modifiable text files, and for the export operation to preserve all images and links in each note.

Answer (score 2):

The Apple Notes program does not offer such a feature, nor does Apple offer other export tools that would handle this.

In regards to exporting as a simple text file - you cannot actually do that while preserving images and other features in the notes. The PDF export is good for "static usage" (i.e. if you're not going to edit the notes afterwards).

If you look at third party solutions, I would look at the following:

Your best bet is probably third party exports such as the "Apple Cloud Notes Parser" project:

https://github.com/threeplanetssoftware/apple_cloud_notes_parser

Alternatively you can run a third party Apple Notes client on Linux and keep using Apple's service:

https://github.com/xfanatical/linux-client-for-icloud-notes

The third option is IMAP: The Notes program supports IMAP accounts. You can use a third party mail service and add that as an account and then copy your notes to that service within Apple Notes. Then you can copy the actual IMAP emails that these notes are stored within on Linux. It is not in a standard format that is readily usable by other notes programs unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will look into all three. Initially I was looking at the Exporter application in the Apple store, but now from what you're said, it wouldn't preserve links and images in a note?

Comment: You never mentioned Exporer before now - so I haven't commented on that before. It uses Markdown, and not plain text files. The image attachment are stored as files alongside the textfile - not inside it.

Comment: So Exporter can do what I want, that is, Exporter can export all notes in the Notes app in one go as modifiable markdown files, and the export operation preserves all images and links in each note? It seems that Exporter does not preserve the structure in each note? That is to say, if I have a note that is written like a scientific report with pictures inserted at specific lines in the note, or under specific paragraphs, Exporter will just create a markdown file and image attachments for that markdown file, with no bookmarks in the markdown file to indicate where images should be?

Comment: I have no information about the app "Exporter" - I would advise creating a seperate question about the app "Exporter" if you are unsure. You haven't mentioned "Exporter" in this question.

Comment: Okay thanks. Let me stay on topic then. What does the parser named "Apple Cloud Notes Parser" parse the notes in Apple Notes to? Does it convert them to a modifiable file which includes links and in-line images? I'm assuming the third party Apple Notes client lets me run Apple notes on Linux, is this right? So if I save all my notes in Apple Notes Mac to iCloud, will I be able to access them from the Apple Notes client on Linux? With this second option I don't have to worry about exporting my notes, yes?

Answer (score 0):

I exported all my Notes by using a modification of the script on [this page](https://macmost.com/export-all-of-the-notes-on-your-mac-using-a-script.html). The result was an html file for each note, which has the advantage of preserving much text formatting and images and can be opened in Word.
The results were not perfect (see below), but it was easy to do. No need to know how to write scripts - just follow the procedure below if you want to try it:

1. Open the *Script Editor* (a program that comes with the Mac OS located in the *Utilities* folder; ie, Go>Utilities)
2. Change the dropdown menu at the upper left to *JavaScript* (see screenshot below)
3. Use File>New and then paste the following code into the Window
   [**note to editor:** I can't get the code below to format properly]

// set things up
var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
var notesApp = Application('Notes');
notesApp.includeStandardAdditions = true;

// choose which notes
var notes = notesApp.notes;
var whichNotes = app.chooseFromList(notes.name(), { withPrompt: "Which Notes?", multipleSelectionsAllowed: true });

if (whichNotes) {

```
// choose save location
var saveWhere = app.chooseFolder().toString();

if (saveWhere) {

    // loop through all notes
    for(var i=0; i<notes.length; i++) {
    
        // is this note one to be exported?
        if (whichNotes.indexOf(notes[i].name()) > -1) {
        
            // save file as html
        var efilename = notes[i].name().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '_').substring(0, 30);
        var filename = saveWhere+"/"+efilename+".html";
            var file = app.openForAccess(Path(filename), { writePermission: true });
            app.setEof(file, { to: 0 });
            app.write(notes[i].body(), {to: file});
            app.closeAccess(file);
        }
    }
}
```

}

It should be noted that this script differs from the one at the top of the [page linked](https://macmost.com/export-all-of-the-notes-on-your-mac-using-a-script.html) according to the last comment on that page by Masoud. Specifically, the lines beginning *var efilename* and *var filename*.

4. run the script (click the arrow in the upper right)
5. select all notes in the "Which notes?" dialog that appears (see screenshot below)
6. in the final dialog select a folder to save the notes

The script ran about 3 minutes for my 260 notes. In some cases strange characters were introduced due to, for example, curly quotes.

Here are images showing the kind of things you'll see in steps 2 and 5
[image]

I'm using Mac OS 12.4 on a MacBook Air (M1, 2020).